# Timeout SSH to public AWS VPC subnet (w/ public IP, routing table to igw, NACL allow all, security group allow SSH, etc.)

Tags: amazon-web-services, timeout, amazon-vpc, vpc

Very weird, have tried everything and no luck.

- Internet Gateway attached to VPC.
- A subnet is created with routing table 0.0.0.0/0 pointing to Internet Gateway.
- Automatic assignment of public IP enabled.
- NACL allows ALL traffic in and ALL traffic out on ALL ports.
- Launched an EC2 instance in said subnet with a public IP and domain name.
- Instance status is healthy.
- Security group on instance allows SSH port 22 and PING from 0.0.0.0/0.
- Flow Log on said subnet shows that inbound connection on port 22 is ACCEPT.
- Ping public IP of EC2 instance receives responses (with loss of packets maybe due to region difference).

Still, cannot SSH into the instance! Have searched all over the net and manual and FAQ, no luck. Please help!

**Additional info: The error was "Connection timeout", it responses that like 1-2 minutes after the ssh command.**

SSH -v output (no useful info seems):

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
ssh: connect to host xxx.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

**I tried associating an Elastic IP to the instance (keep all other settings untouched), SSH was successful. Then disassociate EIP and use old public IP, no luck. [As per documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html) it is not required to use Elastic IP for Internet access, auto-assigned public IP should also work. The same setting worked in the past with default subnets created automatically by AWS, which are public subnets and allowed SSH. Again, very weird!**

The sad thing is I'm not sure how I could debug this situation and locate the real problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What error message do you receive? Does the error come back immediately, or does it take a while (eg 5 seconds) to error? Have you tried it from a different network (eg home vs work)? Do you have any other EC2 instances in the same VPC that _do_ allow SSH? In fact, are there _any_ EC2 instances to which you can SSH (just to rule-out a configuration issue with your corporate network)?

Comment: what is the verbose `ssh` output?. Post the output of `ssh -v .....`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Connection timeout, returned after a long period like 30-90 seconds. Tried both home and office network, same. I added some info in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @helloV the output is not useful, I pasted in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Dai based on `ssh -v` output, either security group inbound is not open or the `sshd` deamon is not running. What type of instance is this? Is SSH server started automatically? I think you are complicating things unnecessarily.

Comment: So it worked with EIP but not auto-assigned? That's weird! When you dissociate the EIP, it will probably get a _different_ auto-assigned Public IP address, so make sure you use the "current" IP address.